# I am getting error on page load in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net when loading image it gives me error as shown below. If i do comment page load code in aspx file it works fine but not working with that.

When i click on the button and go to another page using javascript like this

```
location.href = "productDetail.aspx";
```

It give error like this
[image]
   I tried alot to find out problem some one says that set

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!--<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="600000" />-->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="600000" />

  </system.web>
```

In web.config and some of them says check your url. This is my url
 http://localhost:60340/%3Ca%20href=%27AllScripts/productLightBox/images/Jellyfish178.jpg%27%20class=%27lightview%27%20data-lightview-group=%27example%27%20%20data-lightview-title=%22Navigation%22%20data-lightview-caption=%22This%20is%20a%20testing%20quick%20overview%20where%20you%20can%20add%20more%20view%22%3E%20%3Cimg%20src=%27AllScripts/productLightBox/images/thumbnails/Jellyfish178.jpg%27%20alt=%27%27%20/%3E%3C/a%3E

Please help me i stuck here last 2 days.

Comment: You will have to unravel this for us. Show the Page_load code that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check :

1. `"productDetail.aspx"` exists.
2. `"productDetail.aspx"` resides inside some folder and you have not included its name in the `href`
3. After clicking the target link and keeping a break-point on `Page_Load` of the target page, do you stop on the break-point ? If yes, then you need to post your `Page_Load` code for someone to help.